# selenium not able to click this dropdown link in my UI

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium test case written in python, where the UI looks like this:
[image]

As you may find, I want to click the drop-down button that is circled in red, the xpath value is:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - lan')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']
```

And here is my python code to have it invoked.

```
try:
    dropdown = "//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - lan')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']"

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, dropdown))
    ).click()
    ...
except Exception as e:
    self.logger.info(e)
    raise
```

But somehow during the run-time, it keeps giving me such failure message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <path fill="currentColor" d="M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41zm255-105L177 64c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0L24 183c-15.1 15.1-4.4 41 17 41h238c21.4 0 32.1-25.9 17-41z"></path> is not clickable at point (1027, 920). Other element would receive the click: <div class="profile-save-section">...</div>
        (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.93)
      Stacktrace:
```

Any idea how may I work around such thing ?

Thanks,

Jack

UPDATE,

Following is the screen shot of the URL,  Basically I need to click the "Mode" drop-down link under this "lan" section.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is public?

Comment: Hi Shawn, it is not public, but I have cut paste into the original message. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please never use such long Xpath expressions. They are very hard to read and to understand. If you have a xpath with more than 3 '/' - your are doing something wrong. Avoid div/span[2]/div[3]/... and similar expressions whenever possible.

Try clicking on the SVG like this:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS,
'svg[data-icon="sort"][data-prefix="fas"]')
element.click()
```

In case the CSS query falls on a few elements - you can use find_element**s**. This will give you a list of the the matching elements and you will have to select the correct index and click it.

Comment: This is a fairly complicated profile page that contains lots of layer of objects, I don't know if your "3'/' rule" applies here.

Comment: Did you try my code? Did it worked?

Comment: I did. On that page, there are multiple <div> sections. And If I was to use your code, it clicks the first matching field, not necessary the fields that I want it to be. And that is the reason I am using "//div[contains(text(), 'Interface Settings - lan')]/../following-sibling:: " at the beginning of my xpath.